# How to connect to my network (and the internet) after Debian 11 install with no desktop environment selected?

Tags: debian

I ultimately would like to get openmediavault running and my first attempt at that install led me to the same result as this Debian install with no desktop environment, standard system utilities, and ssh. I was running under the assumption that an internet connection may be more easily attained if I install OPM on top of Debian after researching internet connecting solutions for the fresh OPM install. During the installation of both OPM and Debian I was able to use the internal wireless card on my machine to view and connect to my network.

However, now in both situations when I log in as root in the text only terminal, which is presented after booting, any command that depends on an internet connection fails with errors such as 'Temporary failure resolving 'xxx', replace xxx with deb.debian.org for example.

I suppose I need help determining how to connect to the internet in either one or both instances.

Thank you!

Edit: Essentially my trouble was connecting the computer to my network. I have only use of a terminal command-line. The laptop has both WiFi and ethernet connections. I was able to get up and running with nmtui.

Comment: You’d need to know if your internet is Ethernet or WiFi. How is OPM related to internet? For Ethernet, if your router provides dhcp just install and configure. Similar for WiFi but you will need wpa_supplicant. Depending on those, you may need to also set up resolv.conf. This question is lacking any details on how, so short of guessing no one can help.

Comment: I was able to get up and running with nmtui.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this article, [3 Ways to Connect to WiFi from the Command Line on Debian](https://linuxhint.com/3-ways-to-connect-to-wifi-from-the-command-line-on-debian/)

This is the most straightforward way I have found to interface with the computer to connect to a local network using either an ethernet port or WiFi connection:

1. Run `nmtui` from terminal.
2. Select from three choices

- Edit a connection
- Activate a connection
- Set system hostname

3. To activate a connection over wifi, select `activate a connection`.
4. Network Manager TUI will show wired and wireless available networks, choose the connection and press `Enter`.
5. The next screen will ask for a password, fill it and press `Enter` to continue. Now you will be connected to a network of your choosing.

Comment: It's best to put the essential parts in the answer, so that this answer is still valuable if the link goes stale.